# How to print debug messages in Firebug Lite (Google Chrome extension)?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, firebug, firephp

Does anyone know how to log to Firebug Lite Console using a simple PHP method call to print debug messages (something like the Firephp class for Firebug, in Firefox)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for. It is the chromephp [chromephp](http://www.chromephp.com/) extension